# RoR collection_select (does not work) V collection_check_boxes (works!) - Why?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I am  trying to save some data to my model using collection_select but this doesnt work and I dont understand why. I have tried to use collection_check_boxes which work easily. I am using a HABTM approach and I am confident my model.rb files are coded correctly, so I think something in my view code below isnt correct.

Please can I get some help

----BELOW DOES NOT WORK

```
 <div class="form-group control col-md-12 mb-4">
    <%= form.label :category, 'Pick A Category Most Appropriate' %>
        <div class= 'is-focused field has-addons control is-expanded select is-fullwidth'>
              <%= form.collection_select :category_ids , Category.all, :id, :name %>
        </div>
  </div>
```

----BELOW WORKS OK !

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label "Pick A Category Most Appropriate" %><br />
    <%= form.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |b| %>
      <div class="collection-check-box">
        <%= b.label %>
        <%= b.check_box %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

As can be seen below I get an unpermitted error , but not when using the collection_check_boxes

```
Started PATCH "/listings/1" for ::1 at 2020-01-07 20:33:13 +0000
Processing by ListingsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Y/rvJ3EcwV6iioSV8fXUkkwxRRiZ7o8ZV94sGS5G3liYnghcef2AWBc50g5gX4ULhmGyp163vtVfRAgil8gnMA==", "listing"=>{"name"=>"New Listing", "description"=>"This is a new listing", "category_ids"=>"1", "end_date(1i)"=>"2020", "end_date(2i)"=>"1", "end_date(3i)"=>"6", "end_date(4i)"=>"22", "end_date(5i)"=>"57"}, "commit"=>"Update Listing", "id"=>"1"}
  Listing Load (4.8ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:69:in `set_listing'
Unpermitted parameter: :category_ids
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/listings/1
Completed 302 Found in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 4.8ms | Allocations: 1492)


Started GET "/listings/1" for ::1 at 2020-01-07 20:33:13 +0000
Processing by ListingsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Listing Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:69:in `set_listing'
  Rendering listings/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered listings/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.1ms | Allocations: 313)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 44.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Allocations: 5953)
```

**UPDATE ACTION FROM CONTROLLER**

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**STRONG PARAMS**

```
def listing_params
  params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :description, :end_date, category_ids:[])
end
```

Comment: Could you show your strong parameters call and update action from your controller?

Comment: @BenTrewern - updated question as requested. Its the same setup I have used for collection_check_boxes as I have for the problematic collection_select

Comment: What's happening is your collection_select is passing back a string/integer not an array as required by your strong params.  What happens when you add multiple: true to your collection_select call?

Comment: @BenTrewern - Simple as that !!! Thank you so much . Thought I had tried the multiple: true . But my real intention is to restrict to only a single selection rather than multiple being true . I guess I need to change my model to one to many rather than many to many . Ideas ? On the initial question please submit you answer so I can accept. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment above:

What's happening is your collection_select is passing back a string/integer not an array as required by your strong params.

What happens when you add multiple: true to your collection_select call?

---

I'm guessing what you need is a belongs_to :category relationship in your Listing model:

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  ...

end
```